# How to setup RMI in Glassfish (2.x), so the Remote EJBs would be injected

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, ejb

currently when I deploy enterprise modules manually, their remote EJBs are null (not injected). When I deploy via NetBeans ide, RMI is someway setup and EJBs are injected. My question is what needs to be configured in Glassfish (2.x) so I could deploy modules manually, not via ide.

Answer (score 0):

> (...) what needs to be configured in Glassfish (2.x) so I could deploy modules manually, not via IDE.

Nothing special AFAIK. Either:

- Use **autodeploy**: *copy foo.war/foo.ear/foo-ejb.jar/foo-application-client.jar (anything that can be legally deployed) to the `autodeploy` dir, which is typically `$GFv2_HOME/domains/domain1/autodeploy`*.
- Use the **admin console**: On the right pane, under Common Tasks, click Deploy Enterprise Application (.ear).
- Use the **command line**: with the `asadmin deploy` command line tool. See [`deploy`](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-3675/deploy-1?a=view).

Refer to the [Chapter 3 Deploying an Application](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-3193/gehqs?a=view) for full reference.

Comment: I always deploy via admin console and anything works except remote EJBs.

Comment: @Zeratul How are they packaged exactly?

Comment: They are packaged as jars. They were EJB modules and the web module is war. EJB modules use cross calling of remote EJB interfaces.

Comment: @Zeratul Yeah, I know that they are packaged as JAR. But what does it content exactly? Please show the content of one ejb-jar for one EJB in your question.

Comment: eg: http://147.32.104.190/ejb.png. -- the Validator ejb reference in other module is not injected
On the other thought maybe they all ned to be packaged in single ear (maybe that's what NB does on the background)